# How to display the text progressively in a regular document (not beamer)

Tags: packages

Is there a package possessing `\somecommand` to show progressively the text. I am taking about a regular document class like article.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is some text. % I would like all text before this point appear at the first page.
\somecommand This is some text. % I would like all text before this point appear at the second page.
\somecommand This is some text. % I would like all text before this point appear at the third page.
\somecommand This is some text. % etc

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl

\msg_new:nnn { yourpkg } { invalid-use-of-marker }
  {
    \token_to_str:c {#1}~should~not~be~expanded~when~used~correctly.
    There~is~probably~an~error~before~its~use.
  }

% Try to be helpful when \endPage is not found in the expected place.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \endPage
  { \msg_error:nnn { yourpkg } { invalid-use-of-marker } { endPage } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yourpkg_process_one:w #1\endPage
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl { #1 \par }
    \tl_use:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \newpage
    \peek_meaning:NTF \q_stop
      { \use_none:n }
      { \__yourpkg_process_one:w }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { progressive } { +b }
  {
    \tl_gclear:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \__yourpkg_process_one:w #1 \endPage \q_stop
  }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{progressive}
  First piece of text.
  \endPage Second piece of text.
  \endPage Third piece of text.
  \endPage Fourth piece of text.
\end{progressive}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Depending on what you want to do with it, you might want to add `\unskip` in some place; however, this is not necessary at the end of a paragraph, and `\endPage` does end a paragraph with the above code.

## For people with old `xparse`

In case your `xparse` package is older than 2019-03-05, it won't recognize the `b`-type argument. If this happens to you, either upgrade `xparse` or add `\usepackage{environ}` and replace:

```latex
\NewDocumentEnvironment { progressive } { +b }
  {
    \tl_gclear:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \__yourpkg_process_one:w #1 \endPage \q_stop
  }
  { }
```

with

```latex
\NewEnviron { progressive }
  {
    \tl_gclear:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \exp_after:wN \__yourpkg_process_one:w \BODY \endPage \q_stop
  } []
```

## Other possible syntax

What follows is the first version of the answer with two changes:

- the `tl` var is now global;
- `\startProgressive` clears it (thus, it “starts over”).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl

\msg_new:nnn { yourpkg } { invalid-use-of-marker }
  {
    \token_to_str:c {#1}~should~not~be~expanded~when~used~correctly.
    There~is~probably~an~error~before~its~use.
  }

% Try to be helpful when \endPage or \endProgressive is not found in the
% expected place.
\cs_new_protected:Npn \endPage
  { \msg_error:nnn { yourpkg } { invalid-use-of-marker } { endPage } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \endProgressive
  { \msg_error:nnn { yourpkg } { invalid-use-of-marker } { endProgressive } }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yourpkg_process_one:w #1\endPage
  {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl { #1 \par }
    \tl_use:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \newpage
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \endProgressive
      { \use_none:n }
      { \__yourpkg_process_one:w }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \startProgressive { }
  {
    \tl_gclear:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl
    \__yourpkg_process_one:w
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\startProgressive
First piece of text.
\endPage Second piece of text.
\endPage Third piece of text.
\endPage Fourth piece of text.
\endPage
\endProgressive

\end{document}
```

(same output as above).

Comment: Thank you very much. Why the "Second piece of text" goes to the next line? There in no `\\` (double backslash) after "First piece of text."

Comment: Because there is `\par` in `\__yourpkg_process_one:w` (`\tl_put_right:Nn \l__yourpkg_all_text_tl { #1 \par }`). You can remove it, of course. If you remove the `\par` and add percent signs in the document body, the last page will show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORlmz.png).

Comment: Thank you. Your answer correctly solves my problem. Let me wait a while before accepting the answer in order  to have more chance of alternative answers.

Comment: I added a variant of the code that defines an environment (named `progressive`). `\endPage` shouldn't be used before `\end{progressive}` unless you want to duplicate the last page of the environment.

Comment: Thank you again, for the first solution I get the error `! LaTeX error: "xparse/unknown-argument-type"
! 
! Unknown argument type 'b' for the command '\environment progressive'.` followed by some other compilation errors.

Comment: @Name This means your `xparse` package is too old. See *For people with old xparse* in the updated answer.

Comment: It would be fantastic, if one could modify your code in order to not show again the pages 1,...,n when we are in the page n+1, because we have already seen the content of the pages 1,...,n progressively.

Comment: I don't understand. In the example, you would like to see only one line per page? Then why not simply using `\newpage` after each line? Or, if you want to keep pages 1,...,4 the same as in the example, what is the problem with adding normal document contents such as `abc\newpage def` after `\end{progressive}`?

Comment: Try to put a substantial text (expanding several pages) between `\begin{progressive}` and `\end{progressive}` and put `\endPage` after each sentence and see what happens in the output when the page 2 starts. After the first sentence of page 2, the page 1 reappears. It would be ideal that as soon as page 2 starts, the page 1 is not shown anymore.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, one can put `\end{progressive}` and write `\newpage` at the place when page 1 terminates then beginning a new `progressive` environment. At the end of page 2 one can do the same. The problem is that from the TeX source one can not determine when the page 1 will be terminated.

Comment: I think what you described in the previous comment is the only feasible way with simple code. In order to automatically determine when `\g__yourpkg_all_text_tl` has accumulated more than one page worth of text, you would need to typeset it in a `\vbox` having the same dimensions as the page body (a `minipage` should be fine) and measure its height. There would certainly be fine details that would get in the way (I'm thinking of `\topskip`, `\parskip` and `\parindent`, at least). That is clearly a different question...

Comment: Yes, this is a new question. Your solution here certainly answered my original question as described in the body of the question. I probably ask the new question later as a separate question.

Comment: Another, probably easier way, would be to issue a `\par` after `\tl_use:N \g__yourpkg_all_text_tl` in order to trigger the TeX page builder, then compute `\pagegoal-\pagetotal`. In case this is beneath a predefined threshold, set a global boolean flag so that the next time `\__yourpkg_process_one:w` is executed, it will start by clearing `\g__yourpkg_all_text_tl`. There will be a little amount of unused space at the end of each page that depends on the chosen threshold—or vertical stretching if you replace `\newpage` with `\pagebreak`. If this is acceptable, it doesn't sound very difficult.